# Riemann hypothesis in Zilber's field

Tags: nt.number-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, riemann-hypothesis

**Question.** What is known about the situation (truth or falsity) of Riemann hypothesis in the Zilber's field?

Comment: How does one define an infinite sum in a Zilber field, e.g. the sum for the Riemann zeta function? Does the field have a canonical norm, and if so is there a standard reference for its completeness relative to that norm?